# Right half-plane in resolvent set of $B$. Why is $B$ invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, holomorphic-functions

Let $B$ be a densely defined operator on a Banach space $X$ and let $B$ generate an analytic semigroup on $X$. I know that the right half-plane satisfies $\{Re\ z>0\}\subset \rho(B)$ ($\rho(B)$ denotes the resolvent set of $B$) and $||R(z,B)||\leq \frac{C}{1+|z|}$ for all $Re\ z>0$. Why is then $0\in\rho(B)$?

I know that the resolvent function $z\mapsto R(z,B)$ is holomorphic but how does that help? Thanks.

Comment: The holomorphic function probably does not help. Zero could still be an isolated point of the spectrum, in general. It is not clear what you mean by 'densly defined' (what role this has in regard to the spectrum). Also, it is not clear what $C $ is.

Comment: $C$ is a constant. By densely defined I mean that the domain of $B$ is dense in $X$. So $B$ is possibly unbounded.